# Rails deployment problem : ```App not compatible with buildpack:...```

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, web-deployment, puma

## Issue

This is Rail application, so when I try to deploy on heroku  I got this error on terminal:     remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack...

### Please help.

```
git status
  On branch master
  nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/morning-wildwood-95866.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/morning-wildwood-95866.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:othman-19/social_media.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:othman-19/social_media.git (push)


~/social_media/fb_clone$ ls
app     config.ru  Gemfile.lock  log           public     spec     vendor
bin     db         Guardfile     package.json  Rakefile   storage
config  Gemfile    lib           Procfile      README.md  tmp
```

### Deploy on heroku using:

git push heroku master

### Error log

```
    $ git push heroku masterCounting objects: 1494, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1433/1433), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1494/1494), 564.61 KiB | 5.54 MiB/s, done.
Total 1494 (delta 929), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to morning-wildwood-95866.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/morning-wildwood-95866.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/morning-wildwood-95866.git'
```

## This files used for deployment

### config/puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
    threads_count = Integer(ENV['RAILS_MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
    threads threads_count, threads_count
    preload_app!
    rackup      DefaultRackup
    port        ENV['PORT']     || 3000
    environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'
    on_worker_boot do
        # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
        # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/
        # deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
    end
```

### Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

### config/database.yml

```
default: &default
        adapter: postgresql
        encoding: unicode
        pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
    development:
        <<: *default
        database: fb_clone_development
    test:
        <<: *default
        database: fb_clone_test
    production:
        <<: *default
        database: fb_clone_production
        username: fb_clone
        password: <%= ENV['FB_CLONE_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Comment: plz mark the question as resolved, if its fixed. And you can also remove your answer because its a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the build pack, and make sure you have the right rails directory structure.

```
heroku create --buildpack https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby.git

git push heroku master
```

Comment: What rails version are you using?

Comment: rails version is : Rails 5.2.3

Comment: plz post the complet log of of `git push heroku master`

Comment: Ok it is added.

Comment: also post the result of `ls` and `git status` make sure `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` are added in the git.

Comment: Is it the first deployment? its possible that you have a totally different branch on heroku, you can also force the push but becareful if heroku branch is different it will be overrided. To force: `git push heroku +master`

Comment: You want to see git romote -v ?

Comment: No force push did not

Comment: do you think because every think inside social_media file?

Comment: uha the repo structure is not correct: https://github.com/othman-19/social_media, your rails project is under the social_media directory, actually the fb_clone should be the root. So this should not be a subdirectory of the social meida.